# Logarithm Equality.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\sqrt {\log_a(ax)^{\frac{1}{4}} + \log_x(ax)^{\frac{1}{4}}}  + \sqrt {\log _a{(\frac{x}{a})^{\frac{1}{4}}} + \log_x (\frac{a}{x})^\frac{1}{4}}  = a,$$ for $a>0$ and different than 1... I keep getting $a = 1$, but that cannot be. I use log identities to transform the above into $$\sqrt {\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2\ln | ax |}{4\ln | ax |}}  + \sqrt {\frac{1}{4}\frac{2\ln | ax |}{\ln | ax |} - \frac{1}{2}}  = a $$ which means $a = 1$. Maybe I am overlooking something, but I do not see what.

Comment: In the original question (before edit) many of the parenthesis are imbalanced.  I'm pretty sure the poster intended $...\log_a\left((ax)^\frac 14 \right)...$ as the question becomes a numerical question otherwise.

Comment: I put the equation through mathematica to see what it would give me, but it gave me something that seemed bogus. However, I've never implemented LaTeX in in this forum before, so I just used Mathematica's form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\log_a(ax)^{\frac14}+\log_x(ax)^{\frac14}=\frac{\log_aa+\log_ax+\log_xa+\log_xx}4$$

$$=\frac14\left(2+\frac{\log a}{\log x}+\frac{\log x}{\log a}\right)$$

$$=\frac14\left(\sqrt{\frac{\log a}{\log x}}+\sqrt{\frac{\log x}{\log a}}\right)^2$$

$$=\frac14\left(\frac1{\sqrt{\log_ax}}+\sqrt{\log_a x}\right)^2$$

$$\implies\sqrt{\log_a(ax)^{\frac14}+\log_x(ax)^{\frac14}}=\frac12\left(\frac1{\sqrt{\log_ax}}+\sqrt{\log_a x}\right) $$

and similarly, $$\sqrt{\log_a(x/a)^{\frac14}+\log_x(a/x)^{\frac14}}=\frac12\left|\frac1{\sqrt{\log_ax}}-\sqrt{\log_a x}\right|$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt {
    \log_a\left((ax)^\frac 14\right)
  + \log_x\left((ax)^\frac 14\right)
} + \sqrt {
  \log_a\left(\left(\frac xa\right)^\frac 14\right)
  + \log_x\left(\left(\frac ax \right)^\frac 14\right)
}  = a$$

$$\sqrt {
    \frac 14\log_a\left(ax\right)
  + \frac 14\log_x\left(ax\right)
} + \sqrt {
    \frac 14\log_a\left(\frac xa\right)
  + \frac 14\log_x\left(\frac ax\right)
}  = a$$

$$\sqrt {
    \log_a\left(ax\right)
  + \log_x\left(ax\right)
} + \sqrt {
    \log_a\left(\frac xa\right)
  + \log_x\left(\frac ax\right)
}  = 2a$$

$$\sqrt {
    \log_a(a) + \log_a(x)
  + \log_x(a) + \log_x(x)
} + \sqrt {
    \log_a(x) - \log_a(a)
  + \log_x(a) - \log_x(x)
}  = 2a$$

$$\sqrt {
    1 + \underbrace{\log_a(x) + \log_x(a)}_z + 1
} + \sqrt {
    \log_a(x) - 1 + \log_x(a) - 1
}  = 2a$$

$$\sqrt {
    z + 2
} + \sqrt {
    z - 2
}  = 2a$$

$$z + 2 + 2\sqrt {z^2 - 4} + z - 2 = 4a^2$$

$$2\sqrt {z^2 - 4}= 4a^2 - 2z$$
$$4z^2 - 16 = 16a^4 - 16a^2z^2 + 4z^2$$
$$\frac{a^4 + 1}{a^2} = z^2$$
$$\frac{a^4 + 1}{a^2} = \left(\frac{\log(a)}{\log(x)} + \frac{\log(x)}{\log(a)}\right)^2$$
$$\frac{a^4 + 1}{a^2} = \frac{\log(a)^2}{\log(x)^2} + 2 + \frac{\log(x)^2}{\log(a)^2}$$
$$\frac{a^4 -2a^2 + 1}{a^2} = \frac{\log(a)^2}{\underbrace{\log(x)^2}_y} + \frac{\log(x)^2}{\underbrace{\log(a)^2}_w}$$
$$yw\left(\frac{a^2 - 1}{a}\right)^2 = w^2 + y^2$$
$$\text{...Etc}$$

Comment: Why didn't you use the change base formula instead of substituting with z?

Comment: Since $w=1/y$, we have $yw=1$.

Comment: Sorry, I labeled the values poorly, it's $y = \log(x)^2$ and $w = \log(a)^2$

Comment: Thank you, I see how this works how to derive it, but I'm looking for a method that involves less algebraic manipulation (just for fun). I'm still a little curious as to using the change base formula and my improper result, is there some algebraic law that I'm violating by doing that ?